# Why Does Server Crash On Second Request?

Tags: node.js, express

I  have a nodejs server as shown below. The server is able to set headers when the res.header() statement is not inside a event. It fails when it is executed in resposne to an event like so:

```
app.get('/m/ad', function (req, res) {
  adManager.on('ad_unit_exists', function (ad_unit) {                 
    res.header('Ad-Type',"html");
    res.end();
    return;
  });
  adManager.emit('ad_unit_exists',{});
});
```

Edit: Fails meaning, the server crashes with the following error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.<anonymous> (http.js:526:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (/home/raj/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:44:20)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/raj/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:242:10)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/raj/Projects/adreactor-node/server.js:227:28)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:81:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/raj/Projects/adreactor-node/server.js:232:16)
    at nextMiddleware (/home/raj/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:139:34)
    at param (/home/raj/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:147:16)
    at pass (/home/raj/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:155:10)
    at Object.router [as handle] (/home/raj/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:161:6)
```

Why do you think this is?

**EDIT:** The requests works perfectly for the first request. The server crashes on the second request.

Comment: Added an edit: The first request works. The second request crashes the server with the above error.

Comment: i don't quite get what you're trying to achieve here. why do you emit an event and listen to it at the same time? what exactly is the adManager? why are you working with events and not callbacks?

Comment: Can you help me better understand my similar problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795401/can-someone-explain-this-eventemitter-causes-failure-when-global-variable ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adManager variable is a global variable. For some reason it stores the arguments to the event handlers.

I was using adManager as a sort of global EventEmitter object for emitting events and managing the flow of code.

I had an additional statement outside like so that initializes adManager on server start:

```
 app.get('/m/ad', function (req, res) {

        adManager.on('ad_unit_exists', function (ad_unit, req, res) {               
                   res.header('Ad-Type',"html");

           res.end();
           return;
        });

    adManager.emit('ad_unit_exists',{}, req, res);    
});

AdManager.prootype = new process.EventEmitter();
var adManager = new AdManager();
```

The `res` in the callback for the ad_unit_exists event was being parsed the res from the previous event emission  - the previous request that had already end()'ed - when the event was emitted for  the second request. Strange.

Solved it by adding :

```
adManager = new AdManager()
```

within the app.get() callback function.

Comment: Could you accept your own answer so that this topic can be closed.

Comment: Okay then do that when possible I guess :)

Comment: also if you are only expecting a single event to be fired, it's safer and more resource friendly to just use adManager.once('ad_unit_exists')

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this code can give us a complete picture(function incomplete?). The error tells us you are writing to the socket two times. Probably `res.end()` gets called two times instead of just one time. You should put some debugging statements(`console.log`) in between to get a better picture.

Comment: adManager is a Object() that inherits EventEmitter that's all. I used it as a global variable to emit events to manage flowing the code.

Comment: If possible you should extract code that gives us error. Copy code to a new directory. When you get error, you archive(zip) and upload it to dropbox for example. That way I think it is easier for us to debug. When I look at just those couple of lines I would say it has to work!